# Can I assign the value of a RegEx group to another one?

Tags: c#, regex

Is it possible to copy the value of a group into another one within the regex? Means, I have a text line

```
   errID   name_of_error: description bla bla
```

and I use this RE to save all parts of this line

```
   ^(?'code'[\w\d]{5}) {3}(?'name'[\w\d]+?(?=:)): (?<= )(?'desc'.+?)(?=$)
```

What I would have is an additional group in my regex containing the value of 'code', like

```
   code -> errID
   newgroup-> errID
   name-> name_of_error
   desc -> description bla bla
```

Is it feasible?

EDIT: I'm using C#

Comment: as M42, I'm wondering: which regex engine uses named groups with that `(?'group'...)` syntax?

Comment: You can use this syntax in C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what language you are using, especially for the syntax of the named groups but I think you can use :

```
^(?'newgroup'(?'code'[\w\d]{5})) {3}(?'name'[\w\d]+?(?=:)): (?<= )(?'desc'.+?)(?=$)
```

Moreover `[\w\d]` can be simplified to `\w` then the regex becomes:

```
^(?'newgroup'(?'code'\w{5})) {3}(?'name'\w+?): +(?'desc'.+?)$
```

Comment: @alex555: You're welcome. Could you tell us what language you are using?

Comment: Probably C#, as indicated in the tags: From the docs: (?<name>   ) Captures the matched substring into a group name or number name. The string used for name must not contain any punctuation and it cannot begin with a number. You can use single quotes instead of angle brackets; for example, (?'name'). (See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.71).aspx)